# What would this batch-command look like in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, for-loop, command-line, powershell-core

This works nicely in commandline. Have tried running it in PowerShell without luck, syntax is obviously different.

```
for %%f in (*.hej) do (
    findstr /V "Channel Record TESTBOOL OK OPC Item _COMMCHECK_ SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR Unknown ItemID Field's Connection hutdown acknowledged Alarming Suspended primary SAC reloaded Fix32" %%f > %%f.txt
    del %%f
    ren %%f.txt %%f
)
```

I am looping through all files with hej-ending and delete any row containing any of the words after `findstr /V`.

Edit:
The code works, apart from the encoding, and looks like this per now:

```
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)
$filter  = 'M:\ALM\*.alm'
$pattern = "Channel|Record|TESTBOOL|OK|OPC|Item|_COMMCHECK_|SYSTEM|ADMINISTRATOR|Unknown|ItemID|Field's|Connection|hutdown|acknowledged|Alarming|Suspended|primary|SAC|reloaded|Fix32"

(Select-String -encoding $encoding -Path $filter -Pattern $pattern -NotMatch) |
    ForEach-Object -Begin {Remove-Item $filter} -Process {$_.line | Out-File -Append -encoding $encoding $_.filename }
```

Had issues with encoding but switched from Powershell 5 to Powershell Core, there it worked to type `$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)`.

Latest addition is that I have no write access to the network folder, therefore i would like the "cleaned" files to be stored in a local folder. Have tried to strip `$_.filename` of its path without success by using

```
| Out-File -Append -encoding $encoding c:\temp\(Get-Item '$_.filename').Basename }
```

Cheers

Original data sample:

```
2018-05-19  00:22:07,166 [LUNSC1  ] Fix32.LUNSC1.LUNOP9_COMMCHECK_DV2.F_CV set to 0 by LUNOP9::SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR                 
2018-05-19  00:23:35,226 [LUNSC2  ] Fix32.LUNSC2.LUNOP10_COMMCHECK_DV2.F_CV set to 0 by LUNOP10::SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR               
2018-05-19  00:24:07,169 [LUNSC1  ] Fix32.LUNSC1.LUNOP9_COMMCHECK_DV2.F_CV set to 0 by LUNOP9::SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR                 
2018-05-19  00:25:02,046 [LUNSC1  ] Fix32.LUNSC1.LUNOP9_COMMCHECK_DV.F_CV set to 0 by LUNSC1                                        
2018-05-19  00:25:07,975 [LUNSC1  ] Fix32.LUNSC1.LUNOP9_COMMCHECK_DV2.F_CV set to 1 by LUNOP9::SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR                 
2018-05-19  00:25:35,232 [LUNSC2  ] Fix32.LUNSC2.LUNOP10_COMMCHECK_DV2.F_CV set to 0 by LUNOP10::SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR               
2018-05-19  00:26:00,551 [LUNSC1  ] D_TA204_GT1_DV_AL             CFN              LARM      D_TA204_GT1_Reglerfel                  
2018-05-19  00:27:07,165 [LUNSC1  ] Fix32.LUNSC1.LUNOP9_COMMCHECK_DV2.F_CV set to 1 by LUNOP9::SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR                 
2018-05-19  00:27:35,235 [LUNSC2  ] Fix32.LUNSC2.LUNOP10_COMMCHECK_DV2.F_CV set to 0 by LUNOP10::SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR               
2018-05-19  00:28:01,049 [LUNSC1  ] D_TA204_GT41_DV_AL            CFN              LARM      D_TA204_GT41_Reglerfel                 
2018-05-19  00:28:01,049 [LUNSC1  ] D_TA204_GT31_DV_AL            CFN              LARM      D_TA204_GT31_Reglerfel                 
2018-05-19  00:28:01,049 [LUNSC1  ] D_TA204_GT21_DV_AL            CFN              LARM      D_TA204_GT21_Reglerfel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell something like this would do what you described:

```bsh
$filter  = '*.hej'
$pattern = "Channel|Record|TESTBOOL|OK|OPC|Item|_COMMCHECK_|SYSTEM|ADMINISTRATOR|Unknown|ItemID|Field's|Connection|hutdown|acknowledged|Alarming|Suspended|primary|SAC|reloaded|Fix32"

(Select-String -Path $filter -Pattern $pattern -NotMatch) |
    ForEach-Object -Begin {Remove-Item $filter} -Process {$_.line >> $_.filename}
```

Comment: Great. How could I include -encoding unicode? Namely i have nordic letters as å,ä and ö in the file.

Comment: Replace the redirection operator (`>>`) with either `| Out-File -Append -Encoding` or `| Add-Content -Encoding`.

Comment: Hi. Just replaced it. Have experimented a bit but still don't get it to work as unicode.
`{$_.line | Out-File -Append -Encoding unicode $_.filename }`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52327283/edit) your question and show your updated code as well as an input sample and both the desired and actual output.

Comment: Hi. I know i had this script working earlier, but now all it does it delete my files and doesn't create new ones. Just copied the script above for safety, and it does not work. Ideas?

Comment: @Dan Not without seeing the code you currently have. You may want to post a new question for that.

Comment: Thing is i changed computer to the one that should run the script. Visual Studio Code could not run Powershell 6 on that machine due to a proxy issue. This made the whole difference. Worked when i ran it directly in Powershell 6 terminal. Thanks anyway.